# How to inherit function from a ViewController class

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, inheritance

I am trying to inherit a function `reloadTableView()` from class `HomeViewController`. The function is used to just reload the tableView.

This is the HomeViewController with the reload function declared.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    
    func reloadTableView(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
  
            
        }
        
    } 
}
```

I want to call this reload function from another UIViewController class. Can anyone help me with how I could inherit and use this function

Comment: Where is *"another UIViewController class"*? Did you `push` it onto a navigation controller stack? Did you `present` it?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if you really need to inherit here, but if you want, you can do it like that: `class AnotherViewController: HomeViewController`. Now you can use your `reloadTableView()` in this class.

Comment: My other class is declared like this ```class AssignPageViewController: UIViewController```. If I add the HomeViewController like ```class AssignPageViewController: UIViewController, HomeViewController``` it throws the follwoing error.  "Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'HomeViewController'"

Comment: You don’t need to add UIViewController if you inherit from HomeViewController, because HomeViewController inherits from UIViewController. You can read more about inheritance here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `tableView` is not specifically attributed to `HomeViewController`. Therefore, adding the TableView class directly to `ViewController` could be a solution. However, without seeing the use of `HomeViewController` and `TableView` this may not work if there are functions from `HomeViewController` you would also like to use.

Something like this could work:

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableView = TableView()

    func reloadTableView(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Protocol Extension` is the best option for your need.

Check the sample code bellow

```
import UIKit

protocol TableProtocols {
    func reloadTableView()
}

extension TableProtocols {
    
    //implement your common code here
    func reloadTableView() {
        print("Called: \(#function)")
    }
}

class SomeViewController1: UIViewController, TableProtocols {
    
    func someFunction() {
        //just call that `reloadTableView` method
        reloadTableView()
    }
}

class SomeViewController2: UIViewController, TableProtocols {
    
    func someFunction() {
        //just call that `reloadTableView` method
        reloadTableView()
    }
}

let viewController1 = SomeViewController1()
viewController1.someFunction()

let viewController2 = SomeViewController2()
viewController2.someFunction()
```

Hope this will satisfy your need. If it is, don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.